# How can I copy+paste rich text to just one column on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I've googled this issue and have found plenty of information on how to "split text into different columns", but I want to copy+paste the text into just one column on the google sheet.

Herewith is a picture that shows what I'm getting (on the left), and what I actually need (on the right). I've tried CTRL+SHIFT+V but it doesn't work either. I did it in the past, but can't remember how.

[image: copy+paste comparison]

Comment: Paste it in notepad first may work

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming. Try [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I can recommend to remove all TAB characters from the source (most plain text editors can do it easily) before copy+paste. Yes, no programming, but understanding is important.

Answer (score 0):

Its a two part process.
**1) Find the last column**
Start with the cursor in the first column, press CTRL+Down. The cursor should jump to the next cell in the column. Press CTRL+Up, to move back to the top row. Move the cursor one column to the right and repeat.

It won't take long and you'll find that the cursor goes right to the bottom of the sheet; which means that there's no data in that  column, and the Previous column is the last column.

**2) Concatenate each row**
Go to the first row of data, and create a `Concatenate` formula. Include every column from the first column (B) to the last column, regardless of whether you think there is data in those columns on this row.
Then copy the formula down to the very last row of data.
Then highlight the range, and Copy/Paste Values.

Depending on which are your first and last columns, your formula might look like this.
`=CONCATENATE(C1,D1,E1,F1,G1,H1,I1,J1,K1,L1,M1)`

Answer (score -1):

1. Save the text you want to paste in a text file (ends with .txt)
2. Select file->import in the menu, then Upload, and choose the text file.
   For separator, choose custom, then choose a symbol that does not appear in the text (a letter from another language, for instance). That would make sure that the text is imported into a single column.

Comment: This way may be useful, but the question is about "copy+paste"...

Comment: There is no way to directly copy-paste the data into a sheet without the text breaking into several columns. This answer is the easiest way to achieve the result the poster asked for.